# Inserting special characters inside a string without replacing any character

Tags: sql, string, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Suppose I have a varchar variable.Can I  insert different symbols after evry 2 character of the string untill end of the string .i.e untill length (string).

For example:
Input: '12345678'
And we don't know what is input and length of input and the output we want is :
Output: '12_34&56#78' (special character can be anything )
Please let me know if it possible doing dynamically using loop or something.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a simple `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

The first argument will be your original string.

The second argument will be your regex pattern you want to put a a character after. In this case it is `.` (any character) occurring 2 times. It is surrounded by parentheses which will be needed for the next argument to specify a capture group.

The third argument is using `\1` to specify the first capture group, then you can put anything you'd like to appear after the capture group. In the example below I used a `!`.

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('12345678', '(.{2})', '\1!') as str FROM DUAL;

            STR
_______________
12!34!56!78!
```

If you do not want the character at the end of your string, you can `TRIM` it from the right side or `SUBSTR` if the special character may appear at the end of the original string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply EJ Egyed . Can we add different special characters after every 2 character.Is it possible?

Comment: Using this method, you would have to specify the special characters you would want entered every 2 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an hierarchical query during the split and padding a special character through use of `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` in order to produce some special characters except for the last piece, and then `LISTAGG()` function to combine the pieces back again such as

```
 SELECT id,LISTAGG( SUBSTR(col,1+(level-1)*2,2)||
                     CASE WHEN level < CEIL(LENGTH(col)/2) 
                          THEN
                              CHR(TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(33,48)))
                           END) 
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY level)
         AS result
   FROM t
  GROUP BY id 
CONNECT BY level <= CEIL(LENGTH(col)/2) 
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR ID = ID
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=18a4dfa8c4c14f214ad2df62d07351b3)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for you reply Barbaros Özhan. Can I use set of special characters in the above query or only 1 special character can be declared at a time?

Comment: you're welcome @Astro . You can use `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` function with desired restriction. I preferred the ASCII characters between 33 and 47( above transformation with 33-48 ends with 47 after applying TRUNC function )